# neo4j - construct a cypher query through url

Tags: neo4j

I have a graph-db that I would want to roll out to clients. To better integrate it into their workflow it makes sense if I can auto-generate a cypher query and then serve the results to them in the browser.

I was wondering if it is possible to send in a cypher query attached to the url to auto-generate the subgraph.

Something like:

`http://localhost:7474/browser/MATCH(node:EXAMPLE {name: "Foo"})/RETURN` node

which would run a:

```
MATCH (node:EXAMPLE {name:"Foo"})
RETURN node
```

> Any other way of doing this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to know how to make one or more Cypher queries through an HTTP POST request, you can look at the neo4j [HTTP API](https://neo4j.com/docs/http-api/current/).

Answer (score 0):

I do not get the  "autogenerate" part in your question.

If you want to provide cypher statements as well as the results to users that are not willing/capable of writing cypher statements, your approach is not sufficient. If you do not want to spend time on writing API's and/or creating a UI, you may consider a visualisation /  application development tool like Graphileon ([www.graphileon.com](http://www.graphileon.com))

DISCLOSURE: I am part of the Graphileon team.